HANA SQL CHAR25 with value 1/19/2017 2:28 PM ( example ) to DATE
I have a table ZCRM_DATA
Column - MODIFIED_DATE . Type - CHAR25
Values in column MODIFIED_DATE =
1/19/2017 2:28 PM
11/16/2018 2:44 PM
3/22/2019 12:52 PM
While selecting using data from this table how can I convert the char value in column MODIFIED_DATE to any date format MM-DD-YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD  in a SQL SELECT statement in HANA?

have you tried converting to date first and then using to_nvarchar?

If you want to convert to YYYY-MM-DD :
SELECT 
    TO_VARCHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS MODIFIED_DATE_CONVERTED
FROM 
    ZCRM_DATA

If you want to convert to MM-DD-YYYY :
SELECT 
    TO_VARCHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS MODIFIED_DATE_CONVERTED
FROM 
    ZCRM_DATA


Update :
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_NO, 
    TO_VARCHAR(MAX(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS CHANGED_DATE
FROM 
    ZCRM_DATA
GROUP BY 
    CUSTOMER_NO


Thanks . Is there a way to get the max MODIFIED_DATE in this SQL - SELECT
TO_VARCHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS MODIFIED_DATE_CONVERTED
FROM
ZCRM_DATA

Can you provide an example so I can better understand your request please

For example in table ZCRM_DATA there are 2 columns -  CUSTOMER_NO , MODIFIED_DATE . How to get the MAX(MODIFIED_DATE) from below SQL for each CUSTOMER NO   SELECT CUSTOMER_NO,
MAX(MODIFIED_DATE_CONVERTED) AS CHANGED_DATE
FROM
(
SELECT lifnr,
TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_ON, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')) AS MODIFIED_DATE_CONVERTED
FROM
sapsr3.zpra_crm_data
)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NO

Tried but getting error - Could not execute 'SELECT lifnr, TO_VARCHAR(MAX(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_ON, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS ...' in 101 ms 856 µs .
[303]: invalid DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP value: SQL Error

I tried with temp table and it just works fine create local temporary table #mytemp1 (LIFNR varchar(10), MODIFIED_ON varchar(25));
delete from #mytemp1;
insert into #mytemp1 values('0009022056','10/6/2016 3:11 PM');
insert into #mytemp1 values('0009022056','9/30/2016 2:06 PM');
insert into #mytemp1 values('0009022056','11/7/2016 9:54 AM');
insert into #mytemp1 values('0009022056','10/5/2016 11:17 AM');
select * from #mytemp1;
SELECT     lifnr,     TO_VARCHAR(MAX(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_ON, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS CHANGED_DATE FROM     #mytemp1 GROUP BY LIFNR

But while selecting from real SAP HANA table doesnt work  - Could not execute 'SELECT lifnr, TO_VARCHAR(MAX(TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED_ON, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS ...' in 113 ms 978 µs .
[303]: invalid DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP value: SQL Error
